# slim flash: Passing an array

Tags: arrays, flash, slim

I want to pass an array using [the Slim Framework Flash Messages service provider](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Flash) but my array is converted to a string and therefore the whole thing falls short...

If I understand correctly [the code for the `addMessage` method](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Flash/blob/master/src/Messages.php#L75) it should be working, except it's not.

Here a little example:

```
session_start();

$app = new \Slim\App(['settings' => ['displayErrorDetails' => true]]);

$container = $app->getContainer();

$container['flash'] = function() {
    return new \Slim\Flash\Messages();
};

$app->get('/foo', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $this->flash->addMessage('test', ['key' => 'value']);

    return $response->withStatus(302)->withHeader('Location', '/bar');
});

$app->get('/bar', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $messages = $this->flash->getMessages();

    print_r($messages); // returns Array ( [test] => Array ( [0] => Array ) ) 
});

$app->run();
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It's related to the version of `slim-flash` that you are using. If you check the [differences between the current (only one) version (0.1.0) and master branch](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Flash/compare/0.1.0...master), you'll discover that the bug you're facing was fixed in [PR 12](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Flash/pull/12).

While we wait for another release, you can temporarily use the `dev-master` version in `composer.json` and all will work fine:

```
"slim/flash": "dev-master"
```